Relations between the strong form of Newton's 3rd law and conservation of angular momentum?
How does using the strong form of Newton's 3rd law

Forces between particles come in action/reaction pairs, and these forces are directed along the line of separation between the two particles.

Gives us the conservation of angular momentum.
Although I understand rotational mechanics intuitively like the force required to cause rotation $\tau = Fr\sin(\theta)$
is equal to the vertical component of the force times the distance from the centre, however, I don't understand how this is related to the strong form of Newton's law and how it can be derived from other parts of mechanics.

relevant http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/conser.html

I can recommend 18-2 here - from the Feynman lectures, for a very elegant derivation of the expression for torque from its most elementary geometrical basis.

For a system of $N$ particles with the $i$th particle of mass $m_i$ at position $\mathbf r_i$ with velocity $\mathbf v_i$ , the total angular momentum about some point $\mathbf r_0$ (which we will put at the origin without loss of generality) is given by
$$\mathbf L=\sum_im_i\mathbf r_i\times\mathbf v_i$$
The time rate of change of the total angular momentum is then
$$\dot{\mathbf L}=\sum_im_i(\mathbf v_i\times\mathbf v_i+\mathbf r_i\times\mathbf a_i)$$
The first term in the parentheses is $0$, and the second term has the acceleration $a_i$; we can use Newton's second law to replace it with $\mathbf F_i$, the net force acting on the $i$th particle.
$$\dot{\mathbf L}=\sum_i\mathbf r_i\times\mathbf F_i$$
These $\mathbf r\times\mathbf F$ terms are precisely "the force required to cause rotation" you mention (i.e. torque). In general we would stop here, but let's look at the strong form of Newton's third law.
The net force on each particle is the sum of internal forces between other particles in the system and any external forces
$$\mathbf F_i=\mathbf F_i^\text{ext}+\mathbf F_i^\text{int}=\mathbf F_i^\text{ext}+\sum_{j\neq i}\mathbf F_{j,i}$$
where the force from particle $j$ acting on particle $i$ is $\mathbf F_{j,i}$
Now, let the unit vector pointing from particle $i$ to particle $j$ be
$$\hat r_{i,j}=\frac{\mathbf r_j-\mathbf r_i}{||\mathbf r_j-\mathbf r_i||}$$
If we use the strong form of Newton's third law such that $$\mathbf F_{j,i}=F_{j,i}\hat r_{i,j}=F_{i,j}\hat r_{j,i}=-\mathbf F_{i,j}$$
You will see that the internal torques cancel, leaving us only with the external torques ($\mathbf r_i\times\mathbf r_i=0$, and then the $\mathbf r_i\times\mathbf r_j$ terms all have an equal but opposite pair that cancels out).
$$\dot{\mathbf L}=\sum_i\mathbf r_i\times\mathbf F_i^\text{ext}$$
In other words, if there is no net external torque acting on the system, angular momentum is conserved.

The rotational equations you are referring to are designed to handle rigid bodies.  If you add the rigid body equations to your system (the distance between any two points on an object does not change), you will find that the equations for force and torque can be constructed from the other.

Newton's Third Law can be written as
$$ \vec{F}_{ab} = \vec{F}_{ba} $$
The strong form addendum can be written as
$$ (\vec{r}_a - \vec{r}_b) \times \vec{F}_{ab} = (\vec{r}_a - \vec{r}_b) \times \vec{F}_{ba} = 0$$
Meaning that neither force has a component perpendicular to their displacement vector.
Torque
$$ \vec{\tau}_{ab} = \vec{r}_a \times \vec{F}_{ab} $$
$$ \vec{\tau}_{ba} = \vec{r}_b \times \vec{F}_{ba} $$
$$ \vec{\tau}_{total} = \vec{\tau_{ab}} + \vec{\tau_{ba}} $$
$$ = \vec{r}_a \times \vec{F}_{ab} + \vec{r}_b \times \vec{F}_{ba} $$
$$ = \vec{r}_a \times \vec{F}_{ab} - \vec{r}_b \times \vec{F}_{ab} $$
$$ = (\vec{r}_a - \vec{r}_b ) \times \vec{F}_{ab} $$
$$ = 0 $$
Since $ \vec{\tau}_{total} = 0 $ and $ \vec{\tau}_{ab} = - \vec{\tau}_{ba} $ , the body-to-body forces contribute nothing to
angular momentum. Due to the strong form addendum, external forces would be required to violate conservation of angular momentum.
